# invoking a public function that gives access to a private member(list of strings)

Tags: object, oop, visual-c++, class-method

I set the access modifier of a list containing strings to private and introduced a public function that gives access to it(return type void). I got an error message while trying to invoke the method in the main function.
code is as:

```
class carCompany{

string name;
string owner;
int carsinStock;
list<string> bestsellingCars;
list<string> expensiveCars;
public:
  carCompany(string Name,string Owner){//constructor to avoid redundancy when creating objects
    Name = name;
    Owner = owner;
    int carsinStock =0 ;
  };
  void info(){
    cout<<"Autocompany name: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Company Owner: "<<owner <<endl;
    cout<<"Total cars available: "<<carsinStock<<endl;
    cout<<"best selling cars: " <<endl;
    for(string bestsellingCars: bestsellingCars){
      cout<<bestsellingCars<<endl;
    };
    cout<<"Expensive cars : "<<endl;
    for(string expensiveCars: expensiveCars){
      cout<<expensiveCars <<endl;
    };}
  void importCars() {
    carsinStock++;
  };
  void exportCars()
  {carsinStock--;};
  void bestsellingcars(string cars){
    bestsellingCars.push_back(cars);}
  void expensivecars(string cars){
    expensiveCars.push_back(cars);}    
};






Invoking the function in the main function:







int main(){
carCompany autocomp("Tesla", "Elon Musk");
autocomp.bestsellingcars.push_back("Tesla i");

autocomp.expensivecars.push_back("Tesla ins");

autocomp.info();
carCompany rashidMotors("Rashid motors","Rashid Abu Bakar");
rashidMotors.bestsellingcars.push_back("Porche");

rashidMotors.expensivecars.push_back("Porche carrera");

rashidMotors.info();

return 0;
}
```

The Error message:
invalid use of member'void carCompany::bestsellingcars(std::string)' (did you forget the'&'?)
invalid use of member'void carCompany::expensivecars(std::string)' (did you forget the'&'?)
invalid use of member'void carCompany::bestsellingcars(std::string)' (did you forget the'&'?)
invalid use of member'void carCompany::expensivecars(std::string)' (did you forget the'&'?)

I tried to implement the suggestion provided by the error method but the error was still persistent.

Comment: `autocomp.bestsellingcars` is a function that expects a `string` parameter and returns nothing. It does not provide a method to directly access the list inside the class. Something like `autocomp.bestsellingcars("Tesla i");` may be what you want, but to be honest the names in this class are confusing. Consider something like `addBestSellingCar`. `for(string bestsellingCars: bestsellingCars)` is also weird. If that compiles you should consider renaming the string variable to avoid shadowing the list, it's just confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
rashidMotors.bestsellingcars("Porche");
```